# ¿Porque xampp y mysql?

Tags: mysql, xampp

Soy muy nuevo en bases de datos y no entiendo porque hay que conectar mysql y xampp o algo asi(no estoy seguro si es conectar...) también nose para que sirve xampp en cuanto a bases de datos se refiere, según se, si no se conecta xampp con mysql no se puede crear bases de datos con mysql, etc, algo asi...
Utilizo mysql workbench y no me he conectado con xampp y aun así puedo crear bases de datos, crear tablas, etc
Esas son mis dudas...

Espero que puedan resolver mis dudas. De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!

Comment: Mysql es una base de datos, que puedes instalar sola, sin nada más, y usar con sus clientes. XAMPP es un conjunto de servidores y lenguajes para desarrollo web, que incluyen un servidor web (**A**pache), una base de datos **M**ySQL o **M**ariaDB, que es compatible, el lenguaje **P**HP, y el lenguaje **P**erl. Para usar la base de datos sola no necesitas el resto, pero para hacer una aplicación web que use la base de datos sí necesitas más ingredientes (no necesariamente los que XAMPP te da, pero es una configuración popular)

Comment: La X de XAMPP se refiere a que vale para diferentes operativos, a diferencia de WAMP que era específico para Windows, o LAMP para Linux. El resto de letras son las iniciales del software que instalará. Una vez instalado XAMPP, es común instalar [phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/), que es una interfaz web a la base de datos que se ejecuta sobre PHP, y te permite manipular la base de datos de forma bastante sencilla. _Es para esto en concreto para lo que necesitas XAMPP_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAMPP es un paquete de software libre su nombre es un acrónimo de lo paquetes que contiene que son Apache, Mysql, PHP y Perl.
para crear bases de datos requieres estar conectado a un servidor de mysql que se puede instalar de forma independiente sin usar XAMPP. XAMPP solo te facilita el trabajo de configuración e instalación individual de los paquetes que contiene.
Existen mas programas similares como WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

XAMMP es un paquete que contiene ya el gestor de bases de datos Mysql si te fijas su nombre es un acrónimo : X (para cualquiera de los diferentes sistemas operativos), Apache, MariaDB/MySQL, PHP, Perl. A partir de la versión 5.6.15, XAMPP cambió la base de datos MySQL por MariaDB, un fork de MySQL con licencia GPL. y obviamente no es necesario para crear Bases de Datos...